# Is there a way to change the margins "All" column location for a pandas pivot table?

Tags: python, pandas

I was not able to find a proper solution so decided to ask here. I just wanted to change the "All" column and put it at the start of the "values" column (Before CPU). Is there a way to do this?

Reproducible code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Rep': ['Wendy Yule','Wendy Yule','Wendy Yule','Wendy Yule','Cedric Moss','Cedric Moss','Cedric Moss','Cedric Moss','John Smith','John Smith','Daniel Hilton','Daniel Hilton','Daniel Hilton','Craig Booker','Craig Booker','Craig Booker','Craig Booker'], 
               'Manager': ['Fred Anderson','Fred Anderson','Fred Anderson','Fred Anderson','Fred Anderson','Fred Anderson','Fred Anderson','Fred Anderson','Debra Henley','Debra Henley','Debra Henley','Debra Henley','Debra Henley','Debra Henley','Debra Henley','Debra Henley','Debra Henley'],
               'Product': ['Monitor','CPU','CPU','Maintenance','Software','Maintenance','CPU','CPU','CPU','Maintenance','Software','CPU','CPU','CPU','Maintenance','Software','CPU'],
               'Price': [5000,65000,100000,7000,10000,5000,30000,65000,35000,5000,10000,40000,65000,35000,5000,10000,30000]})

df = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["Manager","Rep"],values=["Price"],
           columns=["Product"],aggfunc=[np.sum],fill_value=0,margins=True)

df = df.reset_index()
df
```

[image]

Comment: instead of screenshot  please copy-paste your code and data in question

Comment: Hi, I added a reproducible code.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `margin_name` argument while creating pivot table to do this. For example

```py
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['A'], index=['B'],
                    columns=['C'], aggfunc=sum, margins=True, margins_name='Grand Total')
```

The margins column will now be named 'Grand Total' instead of 'All'